# How to pass username and password for https call in NSIS

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis

Hi I need to call an https endpoint with username and password specified.

I was trying the plugin [inetc](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Inetc_plug-in). For inetc::get there are options for passing username and password using /USERNAME and /PASSWORD

**/USERNAME**
Proxy username (http only).

**/PASSWORD**
Proxy password (http only). For server (http/ftp) authentication it is possible to use URL encoded name and password, for example http://username:password@nsis.sourceforge.net.

As per the documentation, this works only for HTTP calls. Is there any other ways in NSIS for passing username and password

Comment: Check the sources of the plugin, it might be easy to add that feature for httpS

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @Anders Couldn't get it working.